# This code is showing me an error when i am trying to call user1 from recycler view

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When i was trying to call user1 from recyclerview it crashes i was trying to solve it for hours now but it still if not working so if you can help me i would appriciate it

```
private void readChats() {
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teacher");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                users.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    for (String id : usersList) {
                        if (user.getId().equals(id)) {
                            if (users.size() != 0) {
                                for (User user1 : users) {
                                    if (!user.getId().equals(user1.getId())) {
                                        users.add(user);
                                    }
                                }
                            }else {
                                users.add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), users);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

log cat is showing me error on this code `for (User user1 : users)` 
thanks in advance

Comment: @R7G can you help me with this error

Comment: @RG7 sorry i know i am bothering you allot but i feel like you are the only one who can solve my problems